# Order Documents By Year in CI

Tags: php, sql-order-by, codeigniter-3

I am working in CodeIgniter. I am showing pdf files on a page according to year.

For example I have 3 documents.

1. First document published year = `1983`
2. Second document published year = `2020`
3. Third document published year = `2019`

Now I want document should be displayed in `descending` order. (2020, 2019, 2018 and less year documents)

I am getting documents like this from DB

```
$this->db->where(array('pdf_category' => $category_id, 'domain_id' => config_item('domain_id')));
$this->db->order_by('pdf_date asc');
$query = $this->db->from('pdf_file')->get();
if ($query) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Here in view I am showing like this

```
foreach ($selected_documents as $new_row) {
   $published_year = date('Y', $new_row->pdf_date);
   if($published_year == 2020){
       <?php  $countersix++; if($published_year == 2020 && $countersix==1){?>
        <div class="news-header">
            <h3 style="text-align:center">2020 Documents</h3>
       </div>
      <?php }?>
     <div>  All documents with publish year of 2020</div>
   }elseif($published_year=='2019'){
      <?php  $counter++; if($published_year==2019 && $counter==1){?>
       <div class="news-header">
           <h3 style="text-align:center">2019 Documents</h3>
       </div>
      <?php }?>
      <div> All documents with publish year of 2019</div>
   }elseif($published_year <= 2018){
       <?php $countertwo++; if($published_year==2018 && $countertwo==1){?>
         <div class="news-header">
          <h3 style="text-align:center">Older Documents</h3>
         </div>
      <?php }?>
      <div> All documents with publish year of 2018 and less than publish year 2018</div>
   }
}
```

Here how it is showing

[image]

> But this is displaying wrong. first it should show 2020, then 2019 and
> then 2018 or less year documents.

Now when i try to change my query with this

```
$this->db->order_by('pdf_date desc');
```

it is showing in reverse order like . First it is showing 2018 and older documents. then 2019 and 2020.

**How can I display the documents like first comes `2020` then `2019` and then older document?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem in database.

my **pdf_date** column data type was **varchar**. After changing it to the **int**, results are showing correct order.